# Python Flask server not running inside electron app

Tags: python, node.js, flask, electron

I'm working on an Electron app where I'm running a Python Flask server inside the Electron app. Code has shared below. When I'm trying to run the Electron app by `npm run start` command my electron app is working. But, when ever I'm trying to access my Flask route it's showing error like - "(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

**Electron app folder structure** -

[image]

[image]

**Electron App "main.js"**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process')


const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    });

    win.loadFile('index.html');

};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    spawn("python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])
    createWindow();

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

**Electron App "index.html"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'" />
    <title>My Test App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron renderer!</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p id="info"></p>

    <br><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">Go</a>
</body>
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Python Flask route file - "main.py"**

```
import sys
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World from Flask!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

I'm thinking my flask server is some how not starting. But, I don't know how to see that status of my Flask server inside Electron app.

I'm using "child_process" to run flask server by using following piece of code..

```
spawn("python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])
```

Any idea, what's going wrong. Need some help to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Start the app and then navigate to the server via a web browser. Does it give the same error? If no error then the server is running fine and there is another issue

Comment: Yes. I'm getting the same ```ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED``` error. It means my flask server is really not starting. The way I'm starting my flask app by "spawn" function, am I doing any thing wrong?

Comment: What error is logged in python when you run the server directly and not through electron?

Comment: If I run my python file directly by command prompt using command "python main.py" it's working fine. No error at all.

Comment: When you spawn a process you can attach to the stout. If there is a python error it should output to stout or sterr. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

Comment: Ohh!!! got the error: ```python process stderr:     from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'```
My Python venv is inside "flask_server" folder where I've installed flask. Now when I'm trying to access that from outside virtual environment folder it's not getting that flask module.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide Shall I take out all python files from "flask_server" folder to my electron app root folder? In that way, I think I can fix this issue. But, that will mixup all flask & electron files at one place. Is there any other way, can we fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are trying to spawn the flask server using python and not your virtual environment.

The simplest but maybe not the best way to do this is to change

`spawn("python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])`

to

`spawn("{path_to_venv}/Scripts/python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])`

This will cause the python version of the venv to run and it should pick up the installed packages in the venv.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. After updating by ```spawn("{path_to_venv}/Scripts/python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])``` It's working now. Thanks

Comment: Stuck at a new issue regarding this ```spawn("{path_to_venv}/Scripts/python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])```. On dev enviroment it's working fine. But, the moment I'm building the app by electron forge or builder & clicking on the EXE file it's started showing "error spawn python ENOENT" error. Created a new post at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182377/electron-forge-distributable-showing-error-spawn-python-enoent-when-starting-t