# Electron forge distributable showing "error spawn python ENOENT" when starting the app

Tags: python, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I've one Electron app in which I've used python flask a server with Angular JS for all HTML front end thing. In dev environment it's working fine as I expect. But, after creating a distributable by electron forge when I'm trying to open the `.exe` file it showing this  `Error spawn python ENOENT`.

Distributable creating process by electron forge is going without any issue. But, just after getting the ".exe" file when I'm trying to open the app by clicking on ".exe" file I'm getting this error.

**Error Screenshot -**

[image]

**My Electron app files**

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const { spawn } = require('child_process')


const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    });

    win.loadFile('./dist/angular-flask-electron-app/index.html');
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const status = spawn("./flask_server/.venv/Scripts/python", ["./flask_server/main.py"])
    status.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`python process stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    status.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`python process stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    createWindow();

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

**Flask route file - main.py**

```
import sys
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World from Flask!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

**Folder structure of electron app**

[image]

I can guess like somehow the distributable can't able to package the python inside it. That's why, at the time of opening the file it can't able to make the connection with Python & failed to create the python environment to run the flask route file.

But don't know what to do exactly to rectify this. Need some help.

**-----UPDATE-----**

First I tried Electron Forge to get the distributable. But, when I start getting this error I thought maybe Electron forge is somehow not working properly. Then I tried Electron Builder to get the distributable.

I followed this article to do that - https://medium.com/jspoint/packaging-and-distributing-electron-applications-using-electron-builder-311fc55178d9

The `out` folder structure is like this now -

[image]

**Screenshot for "dist" folder**

[image]

Comment: Show folder structure of the output folder where the exe is

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide Updated my post with the "out" folder structure.

Comment: Oh sorry mb, in C# out is where the exe goes. Can you show me the dist folder. I need to see the final exe and whats with it

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide updated the post with screenshot for ```dist``` folder

Comment: There are multiple issues: First, you shouldn't rely on `./dist` in your application code, but rather make everything relative to the current file, e.g. by using `__dirname`, like shown in multiple Electron tutorials. Second, you're packaging an ASAR. When you're `spawn()`ing, the OS cannot "see" the `python` executable because it's in that ASAR file (think of it as a ZIP archive). Thus, you get `ENOENT`. Such questions have been asked and answered mutliple times here, they're just a little hard to find. Search for problems with ASAR explicitly and you'll get one or more possible solutions.

Comment: (Using `__dirname` you would've seen that `app.asar` is actually in the path given in the error message, since your current file is read by Electron from within the ASAR package. But the OS cannot read ASAR files and spawn applications from inside them.)